# How do I remove the 'last played' games from the steam taskbar?

Tags: steam

Is there any method of removing  the last played games section from Steam taskbar?  I don't use it and it just keeps bugging me.
Added screen and marked spot to show what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not, there is no way to hide recently played games using any of the options available in Steam's settings page - there are options for everything except for recently played games for both the Steam tray icon right click menu and the Windows 7/8 jumplist.